# Error "Function expected" in IE : '<input onclick="start();" ... '

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

There is a piece of HTML:

```
<input onclick="start();" type="button" value="Start!"/>
```

In Firefox and Chrome it invokes `start` on click. However in IE9 it produces the error message: `SCRIPT5002: Function expected`. Then I tried several different cases:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function start(){
            alert("Let's start");
        }
        function stop(){
            alert("Let's stop");
        }
    </script>
    <input onclick="start();" type="button" value="Start!"/><br/> <!-- Failed : the main issue -->
    <span onclick="start();">Start!</span><br/> <!-- Work -->
    <input onclick="stop();" type="button" value="Stop!"/><br/> <!-- Work -->
    <input onclick="start();" type="text" value="Start!"/><br/> <!-- Failed -->
    <input onmouseover="start();" type="button" value="Start!"/><br/> <!-- Failed -->
</body>
</html>
```

1. Original case: Failed <sub>(That's why I'm here.)</sub>
2. Use a `span` instead of `input`: Success
3. Use another function name: Success
4. Use a different type: Failed
5. Use `onmouseover` instead of `onclick`: Failed

I used debugger and it said `start` is `function start(){alert("Let's start");}`. Then I used `alert(start)` and it said `fileopen`.

As the result of test 3, I can easily work-around by changing the name, but I want to know **why this error would happened** in some cases but not happened in the others. <sub>Edit:</sub> Or the next best thing, **other work-arounds without changing the names**.

Comment: first things first, remove all javascript from your html!  keep your javascript in a js file. :)

Comment: @Johan Actually I did, and I got the error, then I put JavaScript in HTML to post here.

Comment: Probably you've redefined another `start` variable with some other type than function. It can also be an `id` of an HTML element shadowing the original global variable.

Comment: @Teemu There are no such things in the code I given, nor in the code I am developing.

Comment: Copying your code into a fiddle and checking on IE 10 seems to reproduce the problem, but it can be fixed by just changing the name of the `start` function to something else. Also, it's better to bind your event handler in JS rather than inline them anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`start` is a property of `input` elements in IE. (According to Microsoft, it indicates, "[when a video clip file should begin playing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)." I have no idea what that means, but it's not important.) In your console, you can see this by running:

```
> document.createElement("input").start
"fileopen"
```

In an element's inline event handler, all the properties of that element are available as top-level variables. It's as if the inline code is run inside a [`with(thisParticularElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) block (where `thisParticularElement` is the element with the listener, obviously). Therefore, in the context of the inline event code, the variable `start` refers to the `start` property of the element, which is a string, not a function.

Simply change the function name, or use `window.start` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

this is interesting. I did few test on my own and it seems that **this error happen** because **start** is already **property of input element**. So it will try to call property, not the function.

I consider it as a bug.

Try following code:

```
<script>
        function autocomplete(){
            alert("");
        }
        function vspace(){
            alert("");
        }
        function hspace(){
            alert("");
        }


    </script>

<input id="error" onclick="autocomplete();" type="button" value="Start!"/>
<input id="error2" onclick="vspace();" type="button" value="Start!"/>
<input id="error3" onclick="hspace();" type="button" value="Start!"/>
```

Then try to debug in console. Also try to `var x = document.getElementById("error");` and then debug x properties.

I tested this in IE8, IE9 and IE10. These functions doesnt work in my IE9 and IE10 (Win 7 32bit).