# javascript onclick() event not working in chrome for text within div container

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

The following is not working in chrome, but works in IE and Firefox:

```
<div id="removeField" onclick="remove(0);" style="cursor: pointer;">-Remove</div>
```

The remove() function does not get called. Any idea why?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you didn't provide the source for the function.

Comment: Provide the code of the function! how could we tell without that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` is a member function of DOM elements in Chrome. In your console, you can see this by running:

```
> document.createElement("div").remove
function remove() { [native code] }
```

In an inline event handler, all the properties (including member functions) of that element are available as top-level variables. Inline code is effectively run inside a [`with(thisElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) block. In the context of the inline event code, the identifier `remove` refers to the `remove` method of the element, not the global-scope `remove` function.

Change the function name to something that doesn't collide with the method names of the element, or use `window.remove` explicitly.

(*Modified from [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150011/710446) handling a similar case with the `start` method in IE.*)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this Chrome bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170395), they implemented a `remove` function which is a **[spec](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-remove)**. Seems that Chrome has a `.remove()` method that allows you to self-remove elements. You'll probably want to name your function something else. Here's the [webkit changelog](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/129400) noting the implementation.