# IE SCRIPT5002 error (Function ecpected)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was looking for that error in stack but didn't find anything about it (exept listeners). So I have code like this:

```
<a onclick="startDownload(447, '63dc7ed1010d3c3b8269faf0ba7491d4', 217)">
```

and my Js is:

```
function startDownload(modId, secret, file){
var transfer = {
    id : modId,
    secret : secret,
    file : file
};

$.ajax({
    url: "download/index",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: transfer,
    success: function(data) { 
      if(data.redirect_failed){
            location.href = data.redirect_failed;
      } else if(data.redirect_success){
            location.href = data.redirect_success;
      }
    }
}); 
};
```

so why this not working with IE? how to fix it?

Comment: Which line is giving that error?

Comment: it says on 662. On 662 line is: `<a onclick="startDownload(447, '63dc7ed1010d3c3b8269faf0ba7491d4', 217)">`

Comment: all versions, IE7, IE8, IE9...

Comment: im getting this error: `SCRIPT5002: Function expected `

Comment: Hum. Try to rename your function in `beginDownload`. Maybe IE think it's a "start" propriety. [[info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149372/error-function-expected-in-ie-input-onclick-start)]